# Is it safe to delete Elasticsearch indices from the file system?

Tags: elasticsearch

When we restart our single node Elasticsearch instance, it starts allocating it's shards.

The allocating of the shards requires more memory then available which is causing the instance to stop working.

We tried to quickly disable the allocation when the instance starts by executing follow query:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "none"
    }
}
```

This call however time-outs because it's busy trying to allocate the shards (with too many resources for it).

The option to increase resources (memory/CPU) is not possible.

The only option that we were left with was deleting the majority of the indices on the file system (when the Elasticsearch instance is down) on the following path:

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch/<id>/nodes/0/indices/
```

Is this considered to be safe? Is this a proper solution? Are there any other solutions like updating the configuration to disable shard allocation?